# Edit files with VS Code ssh tool that require sudo permissions

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am trying to edit some apache configuration files in a server. I would like to use VS code ssh plug in, but I have not found a way to save the configured file, since I am logging into the VM as a user (with sudo permissions) but not root! I get a permission denied error.

I guess there must be a way to just edit the file from VS code (I also tried winSCP, but no result) and when I save the changes, save them as a sudoer.

I heard from a friend that when he tried to save the file from VScode, there is a promt to retry as sudo. I do not get that, and unfortunately I do not now any more details, other than he s using Macintosh.

#### Suggestions I came across and I do not like:

1. Change file ownership
2. Enable root log in

#### Suggestions I tried

1. Tweak with the plug in (Tried to force sudo su as first command, configuring extention.js but there is an error that it writes in an empty pipe)
2. Using winSCP

If someone has a suggestion of using another tool, I am happy to hear it.

#### Specs

Server runs Ubuntu 18, apache and my PC windows 10. If any other spec is required I will edit this section.

**TLDR**.

I need a way to edit a file owned by root, having logged in in as a user with root permissions. I would like to do it through a UI interface since I find difficult editing and creating multiple files through nano/vi.

Comment: For WinSCP, see https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I would not prefer running sftp server on my machine, but I would try it if there s no other way. The thing is, I am not able to use any of the advise on the article, without using SFTP. I cannot even use the sudo -s command from a terminal session, in winSCP

Comment: I'm lost. You do not need to run SFTP on your *local* machine.

Comment: Yeah, I mean running SFTP on my server. I would prefer not too, but I'll try it as last resort. The thing I do not understand is, why can't I just edit a file and then save it as sudo, with ssh, from an editor. There must be a lot of people with a similar problem.
And why am I not getting retry as sudo prompt window

Comment: All Linux servers some with SFTP server built-in. Are you sure you do not have one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually fixed the VS code extension. If you go to the `extension.js` and search the running command (it is an array of functions with string output, joined by one empty space), you will find it named l. Just add to the list of the command

```
"-t sudo su"
```

And it works like charm.

[image: Image of the file]

Comment: It works! tip: after edit close ssh window and open again.

Comment: where would this be in Mac?

Comment: for me there is two files: "C:\Users\blusc\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.80.0\out\extension.js" and "C:\Users\blusc\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-edit-0.80.0\out\extension.js"

Comment: This would be system dependent and foolproof. Looks like minimized code and you will find multiple commands with 'l'. You can't be sure which one to add this to. @George T - do you have a source for this?

Comment: Sorry for my lame question but where is the `extension.js` file please ?

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly the same problem and the only exact answer I found is with:

> SSH FS vscode extension

and

> adding `"sftpSudo": true,` to the "sshfs.configs" section in setting.json (look in the extension settings to find it easily).

It will connect the user with sudo automatically, and then we can modify all files on the fly.

Comment: Can you explain what the question have to do with the SSH FS Extension?

Answer (score 3):

`Save as Root in Remote - SSH` can solve that.

> https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yy0931.save-as-root

It builts on top the official Remote - SSH extension for vscode and let's you save a file as root from the command palette (F1, Ctrl+Shift+P, or Cmd+Shift+P).

It also allows you to save it with root privileges but **as a certain user**. In my case I needed to save it as `www-data`. Works fine.

You have to install the mentioned extension again on the remote after connecting with the Remote - SSH extension to the target machine. After that the `Save as Root` and `Save as Specified User` become available in the command palette:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The given solution by [Georg T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6178296/george-t) is still valid, but the code can look different in newer versions (e.g. version 0.92.0).

For me it was easier to search for "***running script***" and replacing

```
"bash"
```

in the command, which you can see here: [Remote SSH code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUCL3.png)

And the path and file is also still the same:

```
C:\Users\<Username>\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.92.0\out\extension.js
```

Comment: Does not work for me. Replacing "bash" with "-t sudo su" results in `> channel 2: open failed: connect failed: open failed > channel 3: open failed: connect failed: open failed`. VSCode keeps asking for platform, retrying connection in a loop.

Comment: For me, I didn't need the -t or the su.  I just replaced `bash` with `sudo bash` and now it's connected as root.

Answer (score 2):

There is an extension called "Save as Root in Remote - SSH". You can give that a try.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found this extension to be a better alternative for me

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FriedrichVoelker.save-as-root-on-remote

Instead of typing the commands in the save as root remote ssh by yy0931

I can just do ctrl + s and it will request for the password.

Answer (score 0):

This is the configuration that works for me. I'm using **Windows 11** as the client, **VSCode 1.82.0**, **SSH FS v1.26.1**, and **Rocky 8.6** as the destination server. You must find the appropriate SFTP server path on your server.

Press F1 and Open "Open User Settings(JSON)"

[image]

```
{
"name": "server-01",
"privateKeyPath": "d:\#PERSONAL\SSH\id_rsa",
"port": 3223,
"group": "LAB",
"root": "/etc/config",
"host": "10.25.26.27",
"username": "admin",
"label": "lab-server-01",
"sftpCommand": "/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server", // Change this to reflect your server
"sftpSudo": true, // or use a username, e.g., "admin"
}
```

I hope it will help anyone else.

Comment: Hi @prabowo.priyo could you help with an idea of how to config this file to make sudo su - username please?

Comment: You can try to set the target username in the 'sftpSudo' field.